# Are you invulnerable during a Killstreak in Call of Duty Ghosts?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

I've been trying out some of the killstreaks on COD Ghosts and was surprised that I've never been killed while using them yet. I'm not sure if this is pure luck or a game mechanic. For example when aiming the Trinity Rocket or when in control of the Gryphon is it still possible for other players to kill you, or do you become invulnerable when you are controlling these? If you are invulnerable do other players still see you when you have the killstreak tablet out, or do all hitscans simply ignore you for the killstreak duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are using a killstreak, your character will remain in the game as an easy target holding a tablet.

People will see you are using a killstreak, and obviously go for the easy kill. You should always prone or crouch behind cover, or hide somewhere before you use your killstreaks.

If you are killed during a killstreak, you will still be able to continue using it even though you're dead. You will respawn once the killstreak ends.

Comment: Hmm, so it seams that I have been lucky so far. Ok thanks